# Some columns become null when converting data type of other columns in AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I'm trying to move csv data from AWS S3 to AWS Redshift by using AWS Glue. The data I am moving uses a non-standard format for logging the timestamp of each entry (eg 01-JAN-2020 01.02.03), so my glue crawler picks up this column as a string.

In my job script, I am converting this column to a timestamp by using the 'to_timestamp' function in pyspark which seems to work fine. However, as a result of this, columns with a data type of 'long' are not transferred over to redshift and the values for those columns are all null.

When I run my script without converting the timestamp column (I.e just the generated script), I don't have this issue with columns of data type 'long' and they appear in redshift correctly.

Here is my code:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp, col

## @params: [TempDir, JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['TempDir','JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
## @type: DataSource
## @args: [database = "telenors3csvdata", table_name = "gprs_reports", transformation_ctx = "datasource0"]
## @return: datasource0
## @inputs: []
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "telenors3csvdata", table_name = "gprs_reports", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")

# Convert to data frame and perform ETL
dataFrame = datasource0.toDF().withColumn("rec_open_ts", to_timestamp(col("rec_open_ts"),"dd-MMM-yyyy HH.mm.ss"))
# Convert back to a dynamic frame
editedData = DynamicFrame.fromDF(dataFrame, glueContext, "editedData")

## @type: ApplyMapping
## @args: [mapping = [("rec_open_ts", "timestamp", "rec_open_ts", "timestamp"), ("chg_id", "long", "chg_id", "long"), ("rec_seq_num", "long", "rec_seq_num", "long"), ("imsi", "long", "imsi", "long"), ("msisdn", "long", "msisdn", "long"), ("terminal_ip_address", "string", "terminal_ip_address", "string"), ("pdp_type", "long", "pdp_type", "long"), ("ggsn_ip_address", "string", "ggsn_ip_address", "string"), ("sgsn_ip_address", "string", "sgsn_ip_address", "string"), ("country", "string", "country", "string"), ("operator", "string", "operator", "string"), ("apn", "string", "apn", "string"), ("duration", "long", "duration", "long"), ("record_close_cause_code", "long", "record_close_cause_code", "long"), ("uploaded_data(b)", "long", "uploaded_data(b)", "long"), ("downloaded_data(b)", "long", "downloaded_data(b)", "long")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1"]
## @return: applymapping1
## @inputs: [frame = datasource0]
applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = editedData, mappings = [("rec_open_ts", "timestamp", "rec_open_ts", "timestamp"), ("chg_id", "long", "chg_id", "long"), ("rec_seq_num", "long", "rec_seq_num", "long"), ("imsi", "long", "imsi", "long"), ("msisdn", "long", "msisdn", "long"), ("terminal_ip_address", "string", "terminal_ip_address", "string"), ("pdp_type", "long", "pdp_type", "long"), ("ggsn_ip_address", "string", "ggsn_ip_address", "string"), ("sgsn_ip_address", "string", "sgsn_ip_address", "string"), ("country", "string", "country", "string"), ("operator", "string", "operator", "string"), ("apn", "string", "apn", "string"), ("duration", "long", "duration", "long"), ("record_close_cause_code", "long", "record_close_cause_code", "long"), ("uploaded_data(b)", "long", "uploaded_data(b)", "long"), ("downloaded_data(b)", "long", "downloaded_data(b)", "long")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")
## @type: ResolveChoice
## @args: [choice = "make_cols", transformation_ctx = "resolvechoice2"]
## @return: resolvechoice2
## @inputs: [frame = applymapping1]
resolvechoice2 = ResolveChoice.apply(frame = applymapping1, choice = "make_cols", transformation_ctx = "resolvechoice2")
## @type: DropNullFields
## @args: [transformation_ctx = "dropnullfields3"]
## @return: dropnullfields3
## @inputs: [frame = resolvechoice2]
dropnullfields3 = DropNullFields.apply(frame = resolvechoice2, transformation_ctx = "dropnullfields3")
## @type: DataSink
## @args: [catalog_connection = "RedshiftCluster", connection_options = {"dbtable": "gprs_reports", "database": "telenordatasync"}, redshift_tmp_dir = TempDir, transformation_ctx = "datasink4"]
## @return: datasink4
## @inputs: [frame = dropnullfields3]
datasink4 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf(frame = dropnullfields3, catalog_connection = "RedshiftCluster", connection_options = {"dbtable": "gprs_reports", "database": "telenordatasync"}, redshift_tmp_dir = args["TempDir"], transformation_ctx = "datasink4")
job.commit()
```

Is there anything obvious that I am missing here? Many thanks in advance!

EDIT:

After running editedData.PrintSchema() the schema shown is:

```
|-- rec_open_ts: timestamp |-- chg_id: struct | |-- long: long | |-- string: string |-- rec_seq_num: struct | |-- long: long | |-- string: string |-- imsi: struct | |-- long: long | |-- string: string |-- msisdn: struct | |-- long: long | |-- string: string |-- terminal_ip_address: string |-- pdp_type: struct | |-- long: long | |-- string: string |-- ggsn_ip_address: string |-- sgsn_ip_address: string |-- country: string |-- operator: string |-- apn: string |-- duration: struct | |-- long: long | |-- string: string |-- record_close_cause_code: struct | |-- long: long | |-- string: string |-- uploaded_data(b): struct | |-- long: long | |-- string: string |-- downloaded_data(b): struct | |-- long: long | |-- string: string
```

(The longs are part of structs?)

After running editedData.Show(10), The data that should be present in redshift is shown. An example of one of the long columns:

```
 "chg_id": {"long": 123456789, "string": null}
```

EDIT 2:

After running datasource0.printSchema() with no ETL (timestamps are left as strings), the schema is:

```
|-- rec_open_ts: string |-- chg_id: choice | |-- long | |-- string |-- rec_seq_num: choice | |-- long | |-- string |-- imsi: choice | |-- long | |-- string |-- msisdn: choice | |-- long | |-- string |-- terminal_ip_address: string |-- pdp_type: choice | |-- long | |-- string |-- ggsn_ip_address: string |-- sgsn_ip_address: string |-- country: string |-- operator: string |-- apn: string |-- duration: choice | |-- long | |-- string |-- record_close_cause_code: choice | |-- long | |-- string |-- uploaded_data(b): choice | |-- long | |-- string |-- downloaded_data(b): choice | |-- long | |-- string
```

It seems that when I convert the timestamp column, the long columns become structs. Why is this?

Comment: Can you verify the data types and actual data of editedData by using editedData.printSchena() and editedData.show(10) ?

Comment: Yes - I will add the results

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For anyone else that comes across this issue, I've found the solution:

When a type is ambiguous (i.e. in this case, the crawler infers a long but there is a value in that column that is not a long), the type is noted as a choice between the inferred type and a string. If the ambiguity is not resolved, this choice becomes a struct when converting from a dynamic frame to a data frame and is not properly shown in redshift.

Hence, before any ETL is performed I resolved these choices using the 'resolveChoice' method. Here is my updated code:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp, col

## @params: [TempDir, JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['TempDir','JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
## @type: DataSource
## @args: [database = "telenors3csvdata", table_name = "gprs_reports", transformation_ctx = "datasource0"]
## @return: datasource0
## @inputs: []
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "telenors3csvdata", table_name = "gprs_reports", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")

# Resolve type choices
resolvedData = datasource0.resolveChoice(specs = [('chg_id','cast:long')]).resolveChoice(specs = [('rec_seq_num','cast:long')]).resolveChoice(specs = [('imsi','cast:long')]).resolveChoice(specs = [('msisdn','cast:long')]).resolveChoice(specs = [('pdp_type','cast:long')]).resolveChoice(specs = [('duration','cast:long')]).resolveChoice(specs = [('record_close_cause_code','cast:long')]).resolveChoice(specs = [('uploaded_data(b)','cast:long')]).resolveChoice(specs = [('downloaded_data(b)','cast:long')])

# Convert to data frame and perform ETL
dataFrame = resolvedData.toDF().withColumn("rec_open_ts", to_timestamp(col("rec_open_ts"),"dd-MMM-yyyy HH.mm.ss"))
# Convert back to a dynamic frame
editedData = DynamicFrame.fromDF(dataFrame, glueContext, "editedData")

print("Printed Schema")
editedData.printSchema()

## @type: ApplyMapping
## @args: [mapping = [("rec_open_ts", "timestamp", "rec_open_ts", "timestamp"), ("chg_id", "long", "chg_id", "long"), ("rec_seq_num", "long", "rec_seq_num", "long"), ("imsi", "long", "imsi", "long"), ("msisdn", "long", "msisdn", "long"), ("terminal_ip_address", "string", "terminal_ip_address", "string"), ("pdp_type", "long", "pdp_type", "long"), ("ggsn_ip_address", "string", "ggsn_ip_address", "string"), ("sgsn_ip_address", "string", "sgsn_ip_address", "string"), ("country", "string", "country", "string"), ("operator", "string", "operator", "string"), ("apn", "string", "apn", "string"), ("duration", "long", "duration", "long"), ("record_close_cause_code", "long", "record_close_cause_code", "long"), ("uploaded_data(b)", "long", "uploaded_data(b)", "long"), ("downloaded_data(b)", "long", "downloaded_data(b)", "long")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1"]
## @return: applymapping1
## @inputs: [frame = datasource0]
applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = editedData, mappings = [("rec_open_ts", "timestamp", "rec_open_ts", "timestamp"), ("chg_id", "long", "chg_id", "long"), ("rec_seq_num", "long", "rec_seq_num", "long"), ("imsi", "long", "imsi", "long"), ("msisdn", "long", "msisdn", "long"), ("terminal_ip_address", "string", "terminal_ip_address", "string"), ("pdp_type", "long", "pdp_type", "long"), ("ggsn_ip_address", "string", "ggsn_ip_address", "string"), ("sgsn_ip_address", "string", "sgsn_ip_address", "string"), ("country", "string", "country", "string"), ("operator", "string", "operator", "string"), ("apn", "string", "apn", "string"), ("duration", "long", "duration", "long"), ("record_close_cause_code", "long", "record_close_cause_code", "long"), ("uploaded_data(b)", "long", "uploaded_data(b)", "long"), ("downloaded_data(b)", "long", "downloaded_data(b)", "long")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")
## @type: ResolveChoice
## @args: [choice = "make_cols", transformation_ctx = "resolvechoice2"]
## @return: resolvechoice2
## @inputs: [frame = applymapping1]
resolvechoice2 = ResolveChoice.apply(frame = applymapping1, choice = "make_cols", transformation_ctx = "resolvechoice2")
## @type: DropNullFields
## @args: [transformation_ctx = "dropnullfields3"]
## @return: dropnullfields3
## @inputs: [frame = resolvechoice2]
dropnullfields3 = DropNullFields.apply(frame = resolvechoice2, transformation_ctx = "dropnullfields3")
## @type: DataSink
## @args: [catalog_connection = "RedshiftCluster", connection_options = {"dbtable": "gprs_reports", "database": "telenordatasync"}, redshift_tmp_dir = TempDir, transformation_ctx = "datasink4"]
## @return: datasink4
## @inputs: [frame = dropnullfields3]
datasink4 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf(frame = dropnullfields3, catalog_connection = "RedshiftCluster", connection_options = {"dbtable": "gprs_reports", "database": "telenordatasync"}, redshift_tmp_dir = args["TempDir"], transformation_ctx = "datasink4")
job.commit()
```