# AWS Glue: how to cast to an array of integers using ResolveChoice?

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

When loading a JSON using the `glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options` method, if the json contains an empty array, then there is no way to infer the datatype of the array so I get a schema like the following:

```
root
  |-- myemptyarray: array (nullable = true)
  |    |-- element: null (containsNull = true)
```

Is it possible to change the array type using the ResolveChoice operation?

I have tried to specify in the specs something like `("myemptyarray": "cast:array(int)")` and many others but without success. And unfortunately from the code for the python API in [awsglue-libs](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-libs) I cannot infer how to be able to pass the element type to the ArrayType during this casting.

If anybody has discover how to do it, or if it is even possible, it would be much appreciated to share it in here :)

Edit: I'm aware that is possible using pure spark, I just would like to know if there is a way to do it with Glue at the DynamicFrame level.

Comment: have you tried df = df.resolveChoice(specs = [("myemptyarray[]", "cast:int")]) ?

Answer (score 1):

I think for this use-case you would need to use the Spark API directly.

```
dynamic_frame.toDF().withColumn('int_array', col('myemptyarray').cast('array<int>'))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer @RobertKossendey !!, I'm aware it can be done with Spark either programmatically or using spark SQL and do the casting. I wanted to know if there is no way to do it with the ResolveChoice operation :(, you think using spark could be the only way at the moment?

Comment: It seems so, I did not find anything in the documentation. The Glue library is still really immature in my opinion..

Comment: Yeah I got the same feeling :(... I'll just try a few other things and update the post later. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `resolveChoice` here similar to the one explained in the official [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-samples-medicaid.html)

```
dynamic_frame.resolveChoice(specs = [('int_array','cast:array<int>')])
```

Comment: Thanks @Vaebhav, I have also tried that as well, and all I get a IllegalArgumentException: 'Invalid type name array<int>', maybe there is really no way to do it with the resolve choice :(

Comment: Maybe this might help to get some idea - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62409328/some-columns-become-null-when-converting-data-type-of-other-columns-in-aws-glue

Comment: Thanks for sharing @Vaebhav, its quite the same problem I have, the only thing is that in that post he doesn't have to deal with undefined array types, which is what I'm trying to do :(