# Timestamp values are not writing to postgres database when using aws glue

Tags: python, postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I'm testing out a proof of concept for `aws glue` and I'm running into an issue when trying to insert data, specifically timestamps into a postgres database. In my code, when I flip from `dynamic_frame` to pyspark dataframe and convert to timestamp I can see the data as a timestamp but when I try to insert the data I get the following error:

```
ERROR: null value in column "load_dt" of relation "product_staging" violates not-null constraint
```

My code looks like this:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

#Setting up file variables:
quote_chars = '"'
headers =  True
delimiter = "|"
source = 's3'
file_format = "csv"


args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)


# Reading in the csv file with native csv data.
src_data = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    format_options={"quoteChar": quote_chars, "withHeader": headers, "separator": delimiter},
    connection_type=source,
    format=file_format,
    connection_options={
        "paths": ["s3://c108-dev-fpacfsa-crm-stg/decrypted/T002.csv"],
        "recurse": True,
    },
    transformation_ctx="src_data",
)
src_data.printSchema()
# Transform the data to pyspark to handle timestamp data.


py_df = src_data.toDF()
py_df.createOrReplaceTempView("test_schema")
schema_df = spark.sql(
     """
     select 
    product_id
     , product_name
     , product_sku
     , product_retail_price 
     , product_provider
     , product_cd 
     , product_order_cd 
     , to_timestamp(last_load_dt, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")    as load_dt
     , isbn_name 
     from test_schema
     """
 )
# schema_df =  py_df.withColumn(col("last_load_dt"),from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col(""),"dd/MM/yyyy hh.mm")))
schema_df.printSchema()
schema_df.show(trancate=False)

updated_schema = DynamicFrame.fromDF(schema_df, glueContext, "updated_schema")

update_table = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    frame=updated_schema,
    database="store_dev_data",
    table_name="product_staging",
    transformation_ctx="update_table",
)

job.commit()
```

I've referenced [Some columns become null when converting data type of other columns in AWS Glue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62409328/some-columns-become-null-when-converting-data-type-of-other-columns-in-aws-glue)

Could I get a bit more insight as to how to accomplish this task?